# curl_exec maximum execution time

Tags: php, curl, exec

Ok so I have a script that pulls datas from an remote API and inserts them into our own database. The problem is that it works fine for the first 30-40 entries but after that I keep getting Max execution time reached of 60 seconds. Why is that? I mean it works fine at first....

Here is the code:

```
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, self::getCAcertsFilePath());
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($handle);

    if($httpCode == 200){
        return $response;
    }
    else{
        $error_message = self::formatErrorCode($httpCode);
        flash()->error($error_message);
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks for your help,
Ara

Comment: how do you execute your script? post full error message

Comment: why - because it takes more than 60 secounds

Comment: may be you should config your `php.ini` file change this `max_execution_time=60`

Comment: @Lashane My script is executed in a loop till I get all the new datas from the remote API.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Isn't there a way of bypassing this? I don't want to make the script less secure by increasing the max time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your php.ini file and do a search for *max_execution_time*. I think the default should be 30 seconds. You can change it to a bigger number. However, be careful. Don't put a huge number because the bigger the number, the more resources your server will be using.

Comment: Hi, I know this is possible but why is it the first 30-40 entries are working fine but not the one after? I mean it's the same amount of data for every entry...

Comment: the time limit is for the whole script, not each loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your curl using this :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 2000); //in milliseconds
```

for more information, please read [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS.html).
or, you can use

```
set_time_limit(90) // in seconds
```

You can read it in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for more information.